# Using CSS to style data table to remove borders and change data cell height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify data table that i am trying to custom style to remove borders and change the height of the  to 40 px but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is a sample [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/KKKRLMg).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories'
        },
        {
          text: 'Fat (g)',
          value: 'fat'
        },
        {
          text: 'Carbs (g)',
          value: 'carbs'
        },
        {
          text: 'Protein (g)',
          value: 'protein'
        },
        {
          text: 'Iron (%)',
          value: 'iron'
        }
      ],
      desserts: [{
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%'
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.table.v-table.tbody.td,
table.v-table.tbody.th {
  height: 40px !important;
  border: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.20/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.20/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table id="customStyleTable" :headers="headers" :items="desserts" class="elevation-1">
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The CSS that i am using to target the cells doesn't seem to change the height or border but the inspector shows those specified classes. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these should work for you. :) I right-clicked on the table in Chrome and clicked "Inspect" to locate the styles you were trying to override.

```
table.v-table tbody td {
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
}
.theme--light.v-table tbody tr:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css has wrong selector-path, have to be:

```css
table { border-collapse:collapse } // remove border
table td, table th {
  height: 40px; //change the height
}
```